# avr-gcc recompiled ledramp example gets segmentation fault

Tags: avr, avr-gcc, simavr

I have simavr installed on Ubuntu.  I have the following packages installed:
 avrdude binutils-avr gcc-avr avr-libc gdb-avr libelf-dev libglut3-dev gtkwave build-essential.

I tried to run the ledramp example (one example in the simarv folder), works fine. However, when I copy the board_ledramp folder to board_ledramp2 folder, and in the
board_ledramp2 folder, I recompile it and execute it, I got the segmentation fault error.

My commands was:

```
    make clean
    make
   ./obj-i686-linux-gnu/ledramp.elf
```

The console log after make command is:

```
 AVR-CC atmega48_ledramp.c
  1869      32      11    1912     778 atmega48_ledramp.axf
CC ../parts/button.c
CC ledramp.c
LD obj-i686-linux-gnu/ledramp.elf
ledramp done
```

The error message was:

```
Loaded 1850 .text
Loaded 32 .data
firmware atmega48_ledramp.axf f=8000000 mmcu=atmega48
Starting atmega48 - flashend 0fff ramend 02ff e2end 00ff
atmega48 init
Segmentation fault
```

I try to use "file" command to compare the original elf file and
my elf file, the output is the same:

```
./obj-i686-linux-gnu/ledramp.elf: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel
80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for
GNU/Linux 2.6.15, not stripped
```

Anyone can explain what went wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: It's simavr that crashed? Running it in gdb might tell you exactly where. Have you managed to run any other (simpler) self-compiled demo?

Answer (score 0):

From the look of this line:

./obj-i686-linux-gnu/ledramp.elf: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel

It looks like you have inadvertently compiled the program to run on the host PC, rather than an AVR.

Answer (score 0):

@XTL has a good tip here, run the ledram.elf using gdb and see where it crashes. As much as I tried to have the examples ready for 'cut and paste' tweaking, I haven't tried everything.

Another option is to do 'make V=1' and see what's different when compiling the original ledramp and the new one... the original one is build by the 'top level makefile' and it might be subtly different (like, perhaps using gcc vs clang?).

One useful bit would be to get the output you get when doing make V=1 and tell us what compiler version you are using...